# Call org-ref interactivly in org-capture template

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to be be able to call org-ref from within an org-capture template. I have got the org-ref part working, but org-capture is not capturing the reference that is outputted.

I have tried writing org-ref-insert-link as its own function and even to print the output, but org-cature doesn't seem to want to recored anything that org-ref passes.

My current code is:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
        '(("q" "Quotes" entry
           (file+headline "~/Dropbox/Org/quotes.org" "Quotes")
            "** From: %(call-interactively #'org-ref-insert-link) %?" :prepend t)))
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing here? There doesn't seem to be any error output from this, but neither is there a reference.

Comment: `'org-ref-insert-link` operates on a buffer, perhaps appending to a previous link there; you need a function that outputs a string.